# NextJS auth with an external server

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, next.js

I'm working with auth in Nextjs, I'm wondering what is the best strategy to handle authentication in NextJS ?

Here my services structure :

[image]

If I understand well I have to handle the server side rendering in NextJS, so I understand I have to put cookies from my external server to my NextJS client, then handle the server side rendering checkings.  To do that I assume I have to create connection between the NextJS server and the other services. Before dive more deeper in the subject I would  discuss with you about the possibilities available to me. It seems the NextJS auth is a subject in plain development.

Any hint would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I've recently added an [example with cookie auth](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-cookie-auth) which explains what you are trying to do on the frontend.

For the backend, optimally you'll have your API in an external server, apart from the server you use for rendering your Next.js app. This API will handle the database and the token creation business. Then the basics of the authentication are like this:

- The client `POST` a request with username and password to the server.
- The server gets the request and generate a token based on the data received.
- If everything went okay validating the data, the server responds with the token, e.g., `{ token: "secrettoken" }`.
- The client receives the token and saves it in a cookie. Optionally you redirect the user to the `/dashboard` or `/profile` if everything is okay.
- The client, on restricted pages, will check if the cookie exists and optionally validate that against the server, you do this last part in `getInitialProps`. If the cookie validation fails you redirect the user away.

I've created a [small library](https://github.com/j0lv3r4/next-authentication) to abstract this logic.

So in the end, your Next.js app shouldn't know what's happening in the server, it only should receive the token, save it, validate it, and redirect the user if something is wrong.

How you want to handle the token creation, on the external server, is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/153#issuecomment-406823076) thread.  There are several examples of how to do Authentication with JWT, OAuth etc throughout the thread.  You'll see that the examples are utilizing `getInitialProps` and there are several examples utilizing cookies throughout to extract the Authentication tokens.

You'll have to write a custom `server.js` file using `express.js` to serve the tokens through your route requests.  I'm assuming by "external server" you mean some third party Authenticator using OAuth or OpenId protocols to retrieve tokens.  If so, you're right to say that you'll need to request the tokens (or Authentication mechanism) from those external services and then decide how you're going to utilize them in your own client.  You'll probably be using `getInitialProps` to do what you need to do with your Authentication tokens in the client once you are rendering to the browser.

More examples of Authentication [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples) -- one for firebase and another for Apollo.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answers if you want to use Auth0 specifically. In the interview on http://www.fullstackradio.com/112 around the 1:06 min mark Guillermo Rauch mentioned that if he were to implement authentication all over again he would use Auth0, so I created a [minimal repo](https://github.com/awb305/Auth0-Nextjs-Serverless) using Auth0 and Nextjs with Serverless functions.

Like [@jolvera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869996/jolvera) suggested there is an API in an external server, apart from the server used for rendering the Next.js app. This API is located in ./auth/auth.js. It handles the token creation business, and could be extended to handle the database.

The HOC component in ./utils/withAuth.js calls the auth.js lambda for the user information, and is only able to retrieve it if the client side is authorized. Otherwise the user information is undefined. Additionally there is an event listener similar to the one in [with-cookie-auth](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-cookie-auth) which syncs logouts across tabs.

Also one other note, don't get confused with the [Nextjs example on Auth0's blog](https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial/). That example is extending the Nextjs server, and isn't the solution you want if you are deploying Next to *serverless*. It doesn't have the separation of concerns with page routing and authentication.